# For Each loop in Protected String Function

Tags: c#

Trying to add a for each loop in my Protected  string function but keep getting the error: "Not all code paths return a value". Please help.

```
protected string GetAmountStyle()
{
  {
    foreach (LFConnection ProdCurrConn in AllConn)
    {
      if (Login.Contains(ProdCurrConn.UserName) == false)
        if ((Request.Browser.Browser.Contains("IE") == true))
        {
          //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
          //return "padding-right: 1px;";
          return "background-color: #FFFF66;";
        }
        else
        {
          //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
          return "background-color: #FFFF66;";
        }
      else
      {
        //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
        return string.Empty;
      }
    }
```

Comment: hint: What happens if AllConn is empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that, if `AllConn` is empty, your method will never return a value, since you have no return after your `foreach`.

That being said, your loop right now also only checks the first value in `AllConn`, since each path within the `foreach` will return some value, so it's impossible to check the second "Conn" element.

I suspect you really are after something more like:

```
protected string GetAmountStyle()
{
    if (AllConn.Any(ProdCurrConn => !Login.Contains(ProdCurrConn.UserName))
    {
        if ((Request.Browser.Browser.Contains("IE") == true))
        {
            //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
            //return "padding-right: 1px;";
            return "background-color: #FFFF66;";
        }
        else
        {
            //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
            return "background-color: #FFFF66;";
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if AllConn is an empty set what's the return path?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what does your code return if `AllConn` is empty?

Add a default path outside the `foreach`; any of:

```
return "";

return null;

throw new InvalidOperationException("AllConn cannot be empty");
```

(or whatever else you want, really)

Note: it could be that *you* know that `AllConn` is never empty due to some rule that you know about; however - the *compiler* doesn't trust you on this; the logic of `foreach` means that it is not guaranteed to ever enter the inner statements.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the possibility exists that "AllConn" could be empty, thus the conditionals in the loop never get executed, thus the function doesn't return a string. I would include a return statement for the case where the loop never executes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're AllConn collection has no items in it then nothing would be returned. Try this:

```
protected string GetAmountStyle()
{
    foreach (LFConnection ProdCurrConn in AllConn)
    {

        if (Login.Contains(ProdCurrConn.UserName) == false)
        {
            if ((Request.Browser.Browser.Contains("IE") == true))
            {
                //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
                //return "padding-right: 1px;";
                return "background-color: #FFFF66;";
            }
            else
            {
                //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
                return "background-color: #FFFF66;";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //th1.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-right: 5px;");
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```